# Update qdap Dictionary for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: r, nlp, qdap

I am using `polarity` function from `qdap`. There are few words that I want to add to dictionary as negative when said in combination. For instance.

> "Pretty Bad"

The polarity score becomes neutral when this is sent into polarity function.

```
> polarity("Pretty Bad")
  all total.sentences total.words ave.polarity sd.polarity stan.mean.polarity
1 all               1           2            0          NA                 NA
```

Because it considers pretty as good word and bad as bad one, hence the aggregate becomes neutral.

I want to get rid of this and want to add couple of custom words.

Comment: You might want to look at `sentimentr` by the same developer. There you can create new hash values for additional words.

Comment: isn't there such option in `qdap` ? @phiver

Answer (score 1):

To add words in dictionary use sentiment_frame and make your own lexicon. You can add more words as per your requirement. By default polarised words in key.pol is used. check ?polarity

```
library(qdap)
polarity("pretty bad") 
# customised lexicon
positives = c("good","great")
negatives = c("bad","badly")
new_lexicon <- sentiment_frame(positives,negatives, pos.weights = 1, neg.weights = -1)  
counts(polarity("pretty bad",polarity.frame = new_lexicon))
```